# How to create a cookie to identify the user_IDs

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, yii2

In the message center of my website the users can rate and give feedback to each other. Feedback and rating system appears on the screen as a popup window. I have created cookie for this popup window in a way that if a user closes popup window or submits rating/feedback then this popup shows up again only after 24 hours (Cookie expires after 1 day). The problem here is that once the popup 
window which is about rating a particular user is closed/submitted then cookie doesn't let the popup window to open for the other users who are in the chat list (Cookie doesn't identify the users in the chat-list). I want to make it in a way that cookie to identify the users in the chat-list. For example if I submit or close the popup window of a particular user, exactly to that particular user I can only give feedback/rate only the next day. But the other users in the chat list I may choose and give feedback/rate now.

Below see the code.

```
<?

                if($chain_author->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id){
                $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['/message/send-feed/'], 'options' => ['id' => 'send_feed_form', 'title' => Yii::t('title', 'evaluate'), 'style'=>'display:none']]);

                // show star & feedback form
                if(isset($_COOKIE['send-feed-form']))
                {
                    echo 'show nothing';
                }
                else {                  
                echo $this->render('/message/desktop/send-feed', ['chain' => $chain], ['style'=>'display:none']);
                echo \frontend\widgets\FeedStar::widget(['type' => 'form', 'active_form' => $form]);
                $button_options = (!$chain)?['class' => 'button button-send', 'disabled' => 'disabled']:['class' => 'button button-send'];
                echo Html::submitInput(Yii::t('button', 'send'), $button_options);
                echo Html::hiddenInput('chain', $cur_chain);
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                echo '$(document).ready(function() {
                        $( function() {
                        $( "#send_feed_form" ).dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            width: 700,
                            height: 600,
                        });
                      });
                    });';

                echo '</script>';
                setcookie ('send-feed-form', 'yes', time() + 86400);
                }
                ActiveForm::end();
                }
               ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about appending the user id to the cookie name?

```
$id = $chain_author->id;
setcookie ('send-feed-form'.$id, 'yes', time() + 86400);
```

and then select for that specific cookie:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['send-feed-form'.$id]))
    {
        echo 'show nothing';
    }
```

It would look something like this Where $userid is the receiver's id:

```
$userid = $msg->sentFrom->id;
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['/message/send-feed/'], 'options' => ['id' => 'send_feed_form'.$userid, 'title' => Yii::t('title', 'evaluate'), 'style'=>'display:none']]);

if(isset($_COOKIE['send-feed-form'.$userid]))
{
    echo 'show nothing';
}
else {                  
echo $this->render('/message/desktop/send-feed', ['chain' => $chain], ['style'=>'display:none']);
echo \frontend\widgets\FeedStar::widget(['type' => 'form', 'active_form' => $form]);
$button_options = (!$chain)?['class' => 'button button-send', 'disabled' => 'disabled']:['class' => 'button button-send'];
echo Html::submitInput(Yii::t('button', 'send'), $button_options);
echo Html::hiddenInput('chain', $cur_chain);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo '$(document).ready(function() {
        $( function() {
        $( "#send_feed_form"'.$userid.' ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
        });
      });
    });';

echo '</script>';
setcookie ('send-feed-form'.$userid], 'yes', time() + 86400);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer @tbedner. I have tried as you suggested but I am afraid it didn't work. If you have any other solution please share your opinion with me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @RasimAghayev OK, the $id should equal the user id of the person who is receiving the rating, so perhaps I had the wrong value for $id? That way, a cookie will be set for each feedback/rating instance that is unique. Can you confirm that the cookie is being set?

Comment: dear @tbednar, you are right, that was wrong id. I've tried to give value for $id the id of person who receives the rating/feedback. I can say that in this way the cookie is set but the problem is that although I equated $id as following "$id = $msg->sentFrom->id" , in the developers tool I only see cookie name as "send-feed-form1". the number 1 here is the id number of a user who receives feedback. Unfortunately the IDs of the other users who are also supposed to receive are not recognized.

Comment: Also still cookie doesn't let the popup window to open for the other users who are in the chat list, once the popup window which is about rating a particular user is closed/submitted

Comment: @RasimAghayev, so the user who submitted the feedback will not be able to submit more for that receiver, correct? Who are the other users who are also supposed to receive? Are you saying you want to limit the feedback so that a receiver can only have 1 instance of feedback during 24 hours, or that an individual user will not be able to give feedback more than once a day per receiver? If you can clarify, I am sure we can solve this. Thanks.

Comment: You might also have to create a unique id for the form 'id' => 'send_feed_form'.$id and for $( "#send_feed_form"'.$id.' ).dialog({

Comment: Thank you for your interest @tbedner, I really appreciate it. So the logic is as following. In my chat-list I may have 10 users and if I submit or close the rating/feedback popup window of user number 1 for the user number 1 this popup window shouldn't show up during 24 hours. But as soon as I close or submit the popup window of user number 1, I may choose the user number 2 from my chat-list and here the popup window for rating/feedback should show up in order to let me to evaluate the user number 2,3,4 etc.

Comment: So cookie must recognize each user in my chat-list and open the popup window of each user accordingly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your last comment. I am really new in programming, especially in cookies?  If you could apply your solution to my given code I would really be thankful. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, so if your chat-list is small, this will be no problem. The check on the pop-up window will be by unique id/cookie. If your chat list is going to be larger, you can set one cookie with a value that is the receiver's ids separated by commas (or such) that you can then parse in the isset($_COOKIE part. I can certainly elaborate the code and give examples (unfortunately, will not have time today, but can do it tomorrow). Will you have a large chat-list?

Comment: hmm, I am afraid I don't really understand this solution. Could you please show it with codes?

Comment: I have edited the answer to elaborate some. I am not that familiar with the Yii framework, so apologies if there are any issues there. When you echo out blocks of javascript, there could be conflicts if the ids of html elements are not unique. You can right-click > inspect element and then view the console to see if there are any js errors. Chrome also allows you to put breakpoints in the source code to debug js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161235/discussion-between-tbedner-and-rasim-aghayev).